# GnuMake SHELL under windows

Tags: make, makefile

I am trying to make a simple makefile (GNU Make 3.81) work under windows, using cygwin installed with the git-for-windows "distro".

Everything seems to work, but the SHELL. It always shows "sh" being used. The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) has some notes about SHELL on windows, but it mentions COMSPEC, which points to the actual windows shell (cmd.exe) which does not play any role here. Also `$(COMSPEC)` on the Makefile results in a blank string, while `$(SHELL)` is always the path to sh.exe, which is the one being used that I am trying to replace with bash.exe

This is the minimum Makefile to reproduce:

```
$ cat Makefile
SHELL="C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe"

info:
        $(info SHELL is "$(SHELL)")
```

```
$ make info
SHELL is "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe"
make: `info' is up to date.
```

Anyone already figured out how to use bash in this setup?

Comment: `copy bash.exe sh.exe` ?

Comment: thanks @Hannu That is one workaround. But I am trying to make this just to be more convenient to contributors that happen to use windows. I do not want to ask them to overwrite their files, which might create other problems later (what if something need sh.exe?)